# Tricky Combinations Problem with Repeats

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have $18$ elements, $\{A_0, A_1, B_0, B_1, ... I_0, I_1\}$

Now I want to form a sequence of sets, where each element of the sequence is a set of size $3$, where the sets form a partition over my original $18$ elements. An example of such a sequence would be:

$$a_1 =\{A_0, G_1, H_0\}, a_2 =\{B_1, B_0, I_1\}, a_i =\{\dots\}, a_6 = \{ C_1, D_0, G_0\}$$

Now it's not that difficult to find out how many such sequences there are. We can do $\binom{18}3\binom{15}3\dots\binom33$

But what if we want to count the sequences in a manner such that $A_0 \sim A_1, \dots,I_0 \sim I_1$? In other words, $\{A_0, G_1, H_0\}$ and $\{A_1, G_0, H_1\}$ are in the same equivalence class, and sequences $a$ and $b$ are in the same equivalence class if sets $a_i$ and $b_i$ are, for every $i$. How many equivalence classes for sequences are there?

Comment: You can get $\binom{n}k$ with `\binom{n}{k}`. I took the liberty of replacing your $==$ with $\sim$ for equivalence.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about those symbols. Thanks Brian!

Comment: You can calculate the size of an equivalence class as $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of pairs that are in different subsets.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Mark: Let $a=\langle a_1,\dots,a_6\rangle$ be a sequence. If two elements of $a_k$ are equivalent, let $n_k=2^1=2$; otherwise, let $n_k=2^3=8$. Then there are $n_k$ $3$-element sets equivalent to $a_k$ (including $a_k$), and therefore $[a]$ has $\prod_{k=1}^6n_k$ members.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But the question is not to find the size of a specific equivalence class. I need to find how many equivalence classes there are.

Comment: @Mark: I know: I was simply explaining Ross’s comment. It in turn was not intended to be a solution, but rather an observation that might be useful in obtaining a solution.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to the following one: *How many* $6\times 3$ *matrices are there containing each of the integers* $1$ *through* $9$ *exactly twice and satisfying the condition that in each row the entries appear in non-decreasing order?* This observation may be of use to someone. I got what I estimate to be a bit less than halfway (in terms of the work involved) through a brute force calculation before I finally decided that the game wasn’t worth the candle, and so far I’ve not seen a cleverer approach.

Comment: If it's of any motivation, this question is adapted from this year's AMC. So there should be a simple solution using only high school level math.